# The choice of group as coefficient of chain group

Tags: algebraic-topology

> This shows how one can define chains with coefficients from an arbitrary Abelian group. To this end one should consider linear forms $\sum_i g_i \Delta_i^k$ where the coefficients $g_i$ belong to the abelian group $G$. The arising Abelian group of chains with coefficients in the group $G$ will be
> denoted by $C_k(X, G)$.
>
> Anatoly Fomenko, Geometry and Topology Page-23

It seems so in many books we consider the group to be $\mathbb{Z}$ , why is this? When would other groups be useful?

So, far I know some of the homology groups which can be derived from the integer chain group is a topological invariant but are there other reasons?

Comment: because $\Bbb{Z}$ is a very simple and familiar abelian group, so might as well start there. Also, the universal coefficient theorem doesn't hurt

Comment: Oh dayum , that theorem explains it. Thanks @peek-a-boo

Comment: If you chose your group to be a field, then the homology will even be vector spaces over that field, so that you can use all your notions from linear algebra such as dimensions etc. This can be useful (and also just convenient).